# php DOMElement appendchild

Tags: php, dom

Is there a way to append a `DOMElement` directly with another `DOMElement` without going through a `DOMDocument`. I'm trying to make a navigation menu that can be used my another class that houses the `DOMDocument`.

```
        $navItem= new \DOMElement('li');
        $domElement = new \DOMElement('ul');
        $domElement->appendChild($navItem);
```

The `DOMElement` class does extend the `DOMNode` class so it does inherit all of the public methods from `DOMNode`. So in the example above it should be capable of appending the `$navItem` to the `$domElement`.

Instead it returns

> Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'No Modification Allowed Error' in /redacted/navigation.php:15

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

From http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.construct.php

Creates a new DOMElement object. This object is read only. It may be appended to a document, but additional nodes may not be appended to this node until the node is associated with a document. To create a writeable node, use `DOMDocument::createElement` or `DOMDocument::createElementNS`.

Hope this helps you